# What is required to change the vertical offset of a Kendo UI DataViz sparkline?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I am familiar with the `kendoTooltip` plugin and have worked with many other controls, and the typical approach for configuring the plugin does not appear to be working.

Using the sparkline chart, by default the tooltips are displaying just to the right of the cursor. Unfortunately, as you can see in this image, this renders any covered area of the sparkline unable to respond to hover input, meaning, you force the user out of the control and in again in order to see the other values.

[image: Naughty tooltip!]

You can try it out on [Telerik's site](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sparklines/index).

I have tried passing in the config that works otherwise for the tooltip in other areas of Kendo UI, in this case, I've used `position: "top"` and applied it to the widget with the following:

```
        $("#temp-log").kendoSparkline({
            type: "column",
            data: [
                16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 21, 22, 23, 22,
                20, 18, 17, 17, 16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                21, 22, 23, 25, 24, 24, 22, 22, 23, 22,
                22, 21, 16, 15, 15, 16, 19, 20, 20, 21
            ],
            tooltip: {
                format: "{0} &deg;C",
                position: "top"
            }
        });
```

However, this option is not being applied, whereas some other properties are (such as `format` and `visible`).

Is there a way to change the position of the tooltip so it doesn't interfere with user interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the tooltip's anchoring code:

Html target:

```
<span id="temp-log"></span>
```

Chart:

```
var s = $("#temp-log").kendoSparkline({
    type: "column",
    data: [
        16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 21, 22, 23, 22,
        20, 18, 17, 17, 16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23, 25, 24, 24, 22, 22, 23, 22,
        22, 21, 16, 15, 15, 16, 19, 20, 20, 21
    ],
    tooltip: {
        format: "{0} &deg;C"
    }
}).data("kendoSparkline");
```

This will only change the tooltip for this specific chart:

```
var templogHeight = $("#temp-log").height();
s._tooltip._slotAnchor = function(point, slot) {
    var result = kendo.dataviz.SharedTooltip.fn._slotAnchor.call(this, point, slot);
    return {
        x: result.x,
        y: result.y - templogHeight
    };
};
```

([demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/OCEZa))

You could also do this for all sparkline charts by overriding the widget and changing the anchor code in the widget's init method.

Comment: Great, thanks, I'll try this out and mark as answer if this works on my end. Thanks @lars-höppner

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip in sparkline charts doesn't accept a position.

Try http://dojo.telerik.com/@harsh/eNUkO

```
.k-tooltip {
    margin-top:-40px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

If you do not want the tooltip to be on top for other widgets create a class with these styles and add to k-tooltip element when a chart is hovered.

**Or** 
http://dojo.telerik.com/@harsh/OyacA

Html:

```
<span id="sparkline-chart" class="sparkline"></span>
```

Js:

```
$("#sparkline-chart").kendoSparkline({
         type: "column",
         data: [
         16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 21, 22, 23, 22,
         20, 18, 17, 17, 16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
         21, 22, 23, 25, 24, 24, 22, 22, 23, 22,
         22, 21, 16, 15, 15, 16, 19, 20, 20, 21],
         tooltip: {
             format: "{0} &deg;C"
         }
     });

$(".sparkline").on('mouseover', function () {
     $('body').addClass('chart');
 });

 $(".sparkline").on('mouseout', function () {
     $('body').removeClass('chart');
 });
```

Css:

```
 .chart .k-chart-tooltip
      {
        margin-top:-40px;
        margin-left:20px;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks @harsh. Unfortunately, k-tooltip is used elsewhere...like everywhere, and there's no way to isolate the tooltip for the sparkline that I can see (as it's rendered in the root of the `body` rather than in some other container). If you also had a way to isolate the sparkline tooltip, this would work.

Comment: All the sparklines, just not all the charts.

Comment: upvoting since this also works; only drawback is that it can't handle adaptive sizing / resizing of charts

Comment: @LarsHöppner that is simple to handle

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: @whosoever If you find any mistakes in the code downvote and put a comment why it didn't work for you.